# AIX KSH file not found error

Tags: shell, aix

I have placed the .ksh file in a path.
And, I have tried to run that file. But it is showing error like

```
ksh: db2replicator.xxxx.yyy.capture.start.cold.ksh:  not found
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: This means that the file `db2replicator.xxxx.yyy.capture.start.cold.ksh` does not exist.

Comment: What exactly did you place in the path of your .ksh?

Answer (score 1):

The first row of your script must contain a valid shell.

I could reproduce your error message with the following:

```
> cat db2replicator.xxxx.yyy.capture.start.cold.ksh
#!/bin/iDONTexist

date
> ./db2replicator.xxxx.yyy.capture.start.cold.ksh
ksh: ./db2replicator.xxxx.yyy.capture.start.cold.ksh:  not found.
```

A correct first line reads:

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

Answer (score 1):

If the EOL End of line of the ksh file is not saved in Unix format, the error would also occur like this.

ksh: db2replicator.xxxx.yyy.capture.start.cold.ksh:  not found